# Delphi 7 Image limiting from another image

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm doing a game project for school in Delphi 7 and I can't seem to limit a picture which is a JazzJackrabbit character from entering another image which is supposed to be an obstacle. Our teacher said we have to use the Top and left properties to limit the image and this what I coded:

```
IF (imgJazz.Top < image1.Top + image1.Height) then
Begin
  MessageDLG('Careful you just lost life',mtCustom,[mbOK],0);
  iLife := iLife - 10;
  pnlLife.Caption := IntToStr(ilife);
  imgJazz.Top := 136;
  imgJazz.Left := 0;
end;//For IF
```

This statment isn't working because when the image is far away from the image but inline with its Top it still says 'Careful you just lost life'.

Comment: Any chance of you rewriting your post using punctuation and perhaps showing some example code?

Comment: IF (imgJazz.Top < image1.Top + image1.Height) then Begin MessageDLG('Careful you just lost life',mtCustom,[mbOK],0); iLife := iLife - 10; pnlLife.Caption := IntToStr(ilife); imgJazz.Top := 136; imgJazz.Left := 0; end;//For IF

Comment: Hi David there is the IF statment

Comment: You can edit your post. Yes I can see now that the code is there but it is completely unreadable. Please read the formatting guide to format it properly. You also meed to include punctuation.

Comment: Right, I edited it. But please in future can you do this yourself, include punctuation, use capital letters etc. Such details do matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) and as such I won't give you a full solution. I will attempt to guide you towards finding a solution yourself.

The problem is that you have only followed part of your teacher's advice.

> Our teacher said we have to use the Top and left properties to limit the image

You have only followed half of the advice presented here. Follow it all and you will solve your problem.

Comment: Posted as I posted my comment saying the same thing. :) I deleted my comment.

Comment: That was a part of the Coding i have restricted Left aswell

Comment: In other words you failed to post your actual code, you failed to clearly describe how your problem manifests, and you want us to help solve this problem.

Comment: David how would you structure them together for Left and Top because i cant get it right ever!

Comment: Is it possible to approach from below? Your test checks approach from above. And likewise for left. Approach from both left or right need to be detected?